# Help with equation within adjacency matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra, graphs-and-networks

(*Value R seen within desired matrix equation*)
resistance = 0.5;

(*L = ???*)

identitymat = IdentityMatrix[30];
fullmatrix = ((AdjacencyMatrix[plot])) + identitymat // MatrixForm

p.s. I believe I have omitted the a_13 and a_31 entry which should read -1/(RL_13)

Comment: Just a brief remark: Instead of writing `Part[Part[edges, n], 2]` etc. you can make your life easier by writing `Part[edges, n, 2]` or just `edges[[n, 2]]`. Not only is this shorter, it should also put less pressure on the stack (which should improve performance).

Comment: Btw., what kind of weird distance are you computing there? At least, this is not the Euclidean distance...

Comment: I am confused: Is you question about computing `truedistance` or about creating the depicted matrix. Please decide and remove all unneccessary details.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry it was about creating the depicted matrix but included everything for context. Also thank you for the improvement on the truedistance, I'll definitely make use of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use, for instance:

```
{i, j} = Transpose[List @@@ edges];
truedistance = scalefactor Sqrt[Total[Abs[coordinates[[i]]^2 - coordinates[[j]]^2], {2}]];
```

If you actually want to compute the Euclidean distance, then

```
truedistance = scalefactor Sqrt[Total[(coordinates[[i]] - coordinates[[j]])^2, {2}]]
```

would be more appropriate.